# Combine Observables

Tags: f#, observable, reactive-programming

Let say I have

```
A: IObservable<int> 
B: IObservable<int>
```

how can I combine these two into

```
C: IObservable<int>
```

which emitted value is a product of last observed values of A and B?

E.g.

```
A = [ 2   3       1 ]
B = [   2   5  6    ]
```

then

```
C = [   4 6 15 18 6 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not terribly good at f# (more like a novice), but this seems to work:

```
let a = new Subject<int>()
let b = new Subject<int>()

let c = Observable.CombineLatest(a, b, Func<_,_,_>(fun x y -> x * y))

c.Subscribe(fun x -> printfn "%i" x) |> ignore

a.OnNext(2)
b.OnNext(2)
a.OnNext(3)
b.OnNext(5)
b.OnNext(6)
a.OnNext(1)
```

I get:

```
4
6
15
18
6
```